# What should happen with the Expanded Universe tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There are a grand total of [4 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expanded-universe) tagged with [expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expanded-universe), 3 of which are about *Star Wars* while 1 is about *Mass Effect*.

According to the tag wiki, it is intended for

> Generally, expanded universe is the extension of a media franchise (i.e. a television show, series of feature films, etc.) with other media (generally comics and original novels), often with the result being that the stories described in the other media are not considered canon in the original.
>
> With reference to Star Wars: The Expanded Universe (or EU for short) encompasses every one of the officially licensed, fictional background of the Star Wars universe, outside of the six Star Wars films produced by George Lucas. It is derived from and includes most official Star Wars-related books, comic books, video games, spin-off films, television series, toys, and other media. This material expands and continues the stories told in the films, taking place anywhere from over 36,000 years before The Phantom Menace to 134 years after Return of the Jedi. The issue of which aspects are canon is one of the most hotly debated topics among fans. (Wookieepedia)

This would classify it as a meta-tag.

Also, there are a further [51 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bexpanded-universe%5D+%22expanded+universe%22+is%3Aquestion) that are *not* tagged with it, but that *do* contain the phrase "expanded universe", [11 of which](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bexpanded-universe%5D+%22expanded+universe%22+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bstar-wars%5D) are not about *Star Wars* (most of those are about *Star Trek*).

So what, if anything, should be done?

- There is a tag [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) that's already used on [11 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu). Should all questions tagged [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) + [expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expanded-universe) be retagged to that, while all questions containing "expanded universe" and tagged with [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) should be checked and possibly retagged as well?
- Do we need a tag [star-trek-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-eu) for those 9 or so questions containing "expanded universe" and tagged with [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek)?
- Should we remove [expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expanded-universe) from other questions?

Comment: [tag:Expanded-Universe] smells a lot like a meta-tag. Ask yourself,  would you ever tag our search just for [tag:Expanded-Universe]?

Comment: @Pureferret Only if it meant [tag:star-wars-eu].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Richard. It needs to be burniated!

As for the Star-Wars questions, we have a couple options:

- a retag at some point to delineate between Lucas (Legends) canon and Disney canon, somewhat along the lines (like [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) vs [star-wars-disney](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-disney))
- a retag to delineate between films and novels (like [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) for the films and [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) for everything else). This seems like the current system, though minimally implemented and really is outdated with Disney declaring everything on equal footing from here on out
- delete the Star Wars EU tag. Out of 1,391 questions, we only have 11 used, and judging by the number of SW questions that are answered primarily from non-movie sources, could be used a lot more.

Of the three, I'm inclined to just delete the Star Wars EU tag as well, as retagging the likely hundreds of questions that apply to it or the Legends vs Disney canon is not practical and adds little value. Most questions that deal with Star Wars will either specify the canon it is asking from or be obvious as the character or event only exists in one canon.

I can't speak to the Star-Trek tag either, and although the amount of EU material appears to be much smaller, the same argument applies.

**TL;DR**: I would remove all of these EU tags and just let them be identified by the major franchise they are associated with.

Comment: Star Trek has a much narrower definition of canon, and a contradictory EU (there is no effort put forth in making sure all the books work together, or even with canon).  There is no value in a star trek EU tag, EU star trek questions should identify the specific work they are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I vote we destroy it and untag the small number of questions that are using it. It seems pretty pointless.

As @pureferret says in his comment above; would you ever tag our search just for [expanded-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expanded-universe)?